# Complex Power Series Weird Convergence

Tags: power-series

I'm trying to find a compex power series centered at $i$ with convergence radius $\sqrt{2}$ which converges for $z=1$ but not for $z=-1$. Any help?

Comment: The function $\log(1+z)$ is a good starting-point.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}.$$

- It has radius of convergence $R=1$ about $z=0$.
- It diverges when $z=1$ (Harmonic series).
- It converges conditionally for all other $z$ of modulus $1$ (use the [Dirichlet Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)).

How might one alter this series to obtain one with the properties you list?

Comment: I could write it like this $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z-i)^n}{n(1+i)}$. It is centered at $i$, it has radius $\sqrt{2}$, it diverges for $z=-1$ but what happens for $z=1$?

Comment: You're sort of on the right track. You want a change of variables such that the centre $z=i$ becomes $z=0$ and the point of divergence $z=-1$ becomes $z=1$. The substitution $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{-1-i}$ does the trick. Plugging that into the series gives $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n (-1-i)^n} (z-i)^n$ I think.